# After installing opencv, python gives Import Error saying it can't find library

Tags: python, macos, opencv, cmake, kivy

I'm using Kivy on Mac OS X. I installed opencv under Kivy's virtualenv. But then when I tried

```
    import cv2
```

it gave me this Import Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_reg.3.1.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
>     Reason: image not found

But if I move to: cd /path/to/opencv/build
then run python and import cv2, it works fine.

It looks like Python couldn't find the library files from the build/lib directory.

Everything looked fine during the cmake bulding and installation process. What am I missing here?

Thank you!!

Comment: No one knows? Please help.

Comment: did you copy cv2.so from the original installation into ..../venv/python2.7/lib/site-packages?

Comment: see also: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/